# Local Variables and Methods with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am having a problem making a change with an array in Ruby. The method is not able to use the global method. I am confused here and would love some assistance. How can I get an answer from a user and also use that answer?

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

puts "Pick number to insert into array:"
number = gets.chomp()

def insert(answer, number)
  a.insert(1,number)
end

insert(answer,number)
```

Of course I am getting the error:

```
methods.rb:13:in `insert': undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object (NameError)
    from methods.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `a` is not defined within the scope of the `insert` method.

There are several types of variables in ruby, which can be summarised by [the following table](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope):

```
$            A global variable
@            An instance variable
[a-z] or _   A local variable
[A-Z]        A constant
@@           A class variable
```

In order for your code to work, you could either define `a` as a global variable (although this is generally considered bad practice!):

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5]

puts "Pick number to insert into array:"
answer = gets.chomp()

def insert(answer)
  $a.insert(1, answer)
end

insert(answer)
```

Or, you could define `a` within the scope of the method:

```
puts "Pick number to insert into array:"
answer = gets.chomp()

def insert(answer)
  a = [1,2,3,4,5]
  a.insert(1, answer)
end

insert(answer)
```

Or, you could pass `a` into the method as a parameter:

```
puts "Pick number to insert into array:"
answer = gets.chomp()

def insert(a, answer)
  a.insert(1, answer)
end

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
insert(a, answer)
```

Or, you could define a class and make `a` an instance variable of that class - for example, something like:

```
class HelloWorld
  attr_reader :a
  def initialize
    @a = [1,2,3,4,5]
  end

  def insert(answer)
    @a.insert(1, answer)
  end
end

puts "Pick number to insert into array:"
answer = gets.chomp()

my_awesome_object = HelloWorld.new
my_awesome_object.insert(answer)
puts my_awesome_object.a
```

Comment: In your third example, you say Or, you could pass a into the method as a parameter:

this is what I was doing and it isn't working.

Comment: In your original code, you seem to have my-typed or omitted something: What is `answer`? Is that supposed to be the same thing as `a`? I can't reproduce your issue without fully functional code.

Answer (score 0):

Method declaration introduces the new scope. There are many ways to accomplish a task, e. g. with instance variable:

```
@a = [1,2,3,4,5]

puts "Pick number to insert into array:"
number = gets.chomp

def insert(answer, number)
  @a.insert(1,number)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

the method `insert` dont have variable `a`. You must send it there. So modify the code like this.

```
def insert(a, number)
  a.insert(1,number)
end

insert(a, number)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Actually the docs show a.insert as an example... http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-insert

Comment: @arsenalist Yes, but in default or same scope not in method. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike blocks, methods do *not* capture the environment they were created in for the most part, other than object scope if a method is defined inside a class.

In your case, passing `a` explicitly to `insert` could help:

```
def insert(a, answer, number)
  a.insert(1, number)
end
```

If `a` and `insert` go hand-in-hand, a good OO design might be to encapsulate that data and behavior into a separate class. Not sure if it's the case here, but something to keep in mind.